# For a woman, can another woman be a non-mahram?

Tags: terminology, mahram

Women often talk about "non-[mahram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahram) men", and I'm wondering if this is mostly [tautological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(rhetoric)):

**Question**: For a woman, can another woman be a non-mahram?

I recognize there are people who are [agender](http://gender.wikia.com/wiki/Agender) 
or have a [non-binary](http://gender.wikia.com/wiki/Non-binary) gender, so presumably there are "non-mahram non-men", but I'm wondering if the term "non-mahram", when used by a woman, automatically excludes other women.

The Wikipedia page writes:

> A mahram is an unmarriageable kin with whom marriage/sexual intercourse would be considered haram (illegal in Islam).

This seems to imply a woman is mahram to another woman.  However, this also implies that underage boys are mahram, which contradicts a later sentence on the Wikipedia page: "Except for the spouse, being mahram is a permanent condition."  This makes me Wikipedia's definition is not entirely accurate.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Do not use comments for answering questions. If you have an answer to the question, post it as an answer.

Comment: Wikipedia is not the best source for such matters (or any matter), it's a publicly open forum where anyone can contribute with their views - I would advice looking else where.

Answer (score 1):

A 'mahram'  in the marriage context , refers  to being "permanently unmarriageable". so the husband's brother is not mahram to his brother's wife even-though the marriage between them is haram and invalid (because they are only conditionally unmarriageable ) . Also mahram refers to one of the men a woman should travel with and that she can be with without hijab , that's why here a woman is not considered mahram to another woman .  So , the husband is mahram to his wife because she can travel with him alone and he can see her without hijab . that's why they said :

> "Except for the spouse, being mahram is a permanent condition."

because of course if they got divorced he is no longer a mahram.

an underaged boy is not mahram , he is not "permanently unmarriageable" .

a mahram is used for men and women. For example, the daughter is mahram to her father , etc.

In travelling, a woman cannot be a mahram to anybody.

Answer (score 0):

A mahram is someone you cannot marry, but that statement is only true for a legal marriage.

Since in Islam, marriage is only allowed between opposite sexes, and that have come to age (puberty), among other things that constitute a legal marriage, there is no need of reference to specify mahram between two woman (same sex) or towards minor (children).